# How to make python - tkinter dropdown command update after event

Tags: python, tkinter

I am remaking a GUI calculator app in Tkinter, in order to learn about classes, methods, attributes, and also to shorten my original code. In order to shorten the code, I made a frame class that generates frames, entries, labels and dropdown menus, so I don't have to create them individually. Everything went well until I got to the dropdown menu part. When the user selects a different option from the Filters - dropdown menu like V, or B or L etc. the value in frame 1 -> entry[1] doesn't update. The method that updates the value in that entry is called add(self) and it's a part of calculator class.
Here is the simple version

```
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk


window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("920x500")
window.resizable(0,0)
window.title('Exposure Time Calculator')


class Calculator:
    
    def __init__(self, window):
        
        self.create_test_frame1()
        self.create_test_frame2()
        self.add(None)
        
    def create_test_frame1(self):
        
        labelvalues=['val 1','val 2']
        entryvalues=['203','1333']
        self.frame_1 = frame('Test Frame 1',labelvalues,entryvalues,6, 2, 0, 0, "no",0,0,0,0,0,30,40)

    def create_test_frame2(self):
        labelvalues = ['val 3','val 4']
        entryvalues = ['10','24.5']
        option_menu_values = ['B','V','R','I','Luminance','Hydrogen 3nm']
        
       
        
        self.frame_2 = frame('Frame 2', labelvalues, entryvalues, 14, 2, 0, 2, 
                                  "option_menu1_yes", option_menu_values,'Filters',
                                  0,0,0,
                                  5,20)
    
    def add(self, e):
       
       qe = self.frame_1.entry[1]
       bandOption = self.frame_2.clicked.get()
      
       if bandOption == "B":
           
           qe.delete(0,tk.END)
           qe.insert(0,22)
       elif bandOption == "V":
           qe.delete(0,tk.END)
           qe.insert(0,33)
        
    
    
class frame:
#                       Creates a frame class for automatic frame generation
#                         with entries, labels and/or option menus
# 1. name : frame name
# 2. label_default_values: name of labels
# 3. entry_default_values: default values in entries
# 4. entry_width: the entries dimensions
# 5. I: number of labels and entries
# 6. grid_row: frame grid row placement
# 7. grid_column: frame grid column placement
# 8. option_menu: true or false if user wants a option list or not
# 9. option_list_values: list for option menu
# 10. option_label: name for option menu label
# 11. ipax, ipady: padding
# 12. comand: comand for option list

    def __init__(self, name, label_default_values, entry_default_values, entry_width, I, grid_row, grid_column, 
                 option_menu1, option_list_values, option_label, 
                 option_menu2, option2_list_values,option_label2,
                 ipad_x, ipad_y
                ):
        
        self.name = name
        self.label_default_values = label_default_values
        self.entry_default_values = entry_default_values
        self.I = I
        self.grid_row = grid_row
        self.grid_column = grid_column
        self.dropMenu_options = option_list_values
        self.label = option_label
        self.entry_width = entry_width
        self.dropMenu_options2 = option2_list_values
        self.option_label2 = option_label2
        self.ipad_x = ipad_x
        self.ipad_y = ipad_y
        

        frame = tk.LabelFrame(window, text = name, highlightbackground='grey', highlightthickness=1)
        frame.grid(row=self.grid_row, column=self.grid_column, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=ipad_x, ipady=ipad_y)
       
        if option_menu1 == "option_menu1_yes":
         
            
            self.clicked = tk.StringVar()
            self.clicked.set(self.dropMenu_options[0])
            self.drop = tk.OptionMenu(frame, self.clicked, *self.dropMenu_options, command = self.add)
            self.drop.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky="ew")
            label = tk.Label(frame, text = option_label, highlightbackground='grey', highlightthickness=1)
            label.grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = "w")
        
        if option_menu2 == "option_menu2_yes":
            self.clicked2 = tk.StringVar()
            self.clicked2.set(self.dropMenu_options2[0])
            self.drop2 = tk.OptionMenu(frame, self.clicked2, *self.dropMenu_options2)
            self.drop2.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky="ew")
            label = tk.Label(frame, text = option_label2, highlightbackground='grey', highlightthickness=1)
            label.grid(row = 6, column = 0, sticky = "w")
            
        
        self.entry ={}

        for i in range(0, self.I):
         
            label = tk.Label(frame, text = self.label_default_values[i], justify = "left")
            label.grid(row=i, column=0, sticky = "w")
            
            self.entry[i] = tk.Entry(frame, textvariable = float(self.entry_default_values[i]), width=self.entry_width)
            self.entry[i].grid(row=i, column=1, sticky = "e")
            self.entry[i].delete(0, tk.END)
            self.entry[i].insert(0, self.entry_default_values[i])  

c=Calculator(window)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I copy-pasted the entire code and it works, what's the problem?

Comment: does it update the QE entry if you change the band from B to V or R or I etc ... ?

Comment: No, is this the problem?

Comment: Yes, that is the problem,  it doesn't update if if chose V or I or etc.

Comment: The add method should be inside the frame class

Comment: This code has multiple different errors of different types. To fix it would require quite some work rearranging code and tracking down errors. By the way, just a syntax tip: class names should be written in `CamelCase`. Have you tried using `def add(self, *args):`? That should fix the error messages mentioned in your question.

Comment: Please try to reduce this code down to a [mcve]. If the problem is with an interaction between a dropdown and entry, we don't need much more than one dropdown and one entry and enough code to glue it together.

Comment: Ok I will re-edit with a simpler example

Comment: The `add` method in your code isn't defined to accept a parameter other than `self` so it can't generate the error you say it does.

Comment: Your code will be easier to understand by others if you make  your class names start with an uppercase character as per [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: I've made a simpler example, if it helps

Comment: It appears you have a crucial error in your code. Your `frame` class is inheriting from `Calculator`, but `Calculator` uses `frame` as a component.  You aren't properly initializing the superclass, though if you did you would end up in with a recursion error. Inheritance isn't for sharing components, and `frame` shouldn't be inheriting from `Calculator` since `frame` itself is not a `Calculator`.

Comment: Thank you, I removed the inheritance

Comment: The code you posted fails with an error. Please try to post running code.

Comment: Why there is no 12th argument, the callback for option list, as mentioned in the comment of `frame` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `add` is in the `Calculator` class, so instead of `self.add` you need to call `add` on the calculator. Since the frame doesn't know what the calculator is, you need to pass it in when constructing the frame.

Something like the following, where the calculator instance is passed as the first option:

```
self.frame_1 = frame(self, 'Test Frame 1', ...)
```

Next, you need to define your class to accept and save the reference to the calculator and then use it in the `command` of the `OptionMenu`:

```
class frame:
    def __init__(self, calculator, name, ...):
        self.calculator = calculator
        ...
        self.drop = tk.OptionMenu(..., command = self.calculator.add)
```

Also, you define `add` like this:

```
def add(self, e):
```

I assume that means you think the second parameter is an event object. It is not. It is the value that was picked from the optionmenu.

Arguably, a better way to define this would be to actually use this new value if provided, and fall back to calling `get` if a value isn't provided. Also, you can reduce the wall of if statements into a single dictionary lookup to make the code shorter and more robust.

```
def add(self, new_value=None):

   qe = self.frame_1.entry[1]
   bandOption = self.frame_2.clicked.get() if new_value is None else new_value

   band = {"B": 22, "V": 33}
   qe.delete(0, "end")
   qe.insert(0, band[bandOption])
```

This solution is 2/3 the size of your original, and more flexible and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems:

- The first one is that you mentioned and to fix it:
  rename `def add(self)` to `def add(self, e)` and rename `add()` to `add(None)`. Then change `lambda event: self.add` to `self.add`
- The second one is:
  `AttributeError: 'frame' object has no attribute 'frame_camera'`
  but is not question related

Comment: As I stated in my comment, another option for `add()` is to use `*args`. This would be fine, since the event being passed to `add()` isn't being used, and therefore doesn't need a variable name of it's own. It also means you don't have to pass `None` when calling `add()` by itself.

Comment: Yes I also changed the lamda to self.add but now I get the second error you've mentioned. Maybe I went over my head with the frame class

Comment: I will try some solution

Comment: Thank you for helping, I think I should make a small test with 2 frames, 2 entries and 1 dropdown option.

Comment: another option is `def add(self, event=None)` so that you can call it with or without a parameter.

Answer (score -1):

It works if I define add(event) outside classes.

```
def add(event):
   
   qe = c.frame_1.entry[1]
   bandOption = c.frame_2.clicked.get()
  
   if bandOption == "B":
       qe.delete(0,tk.END)
       qe.insert(0,22)
   elif bandOption == "V":
       qe.delete(0,tk.END)
       qe.insert(0,33)
```

And this in the frame class:

```
self.drop = tk.OptionMenu(frame, self.clicked, *self.dropMenu_options, command = lambda event:add(event))
```